# Add a value to a checkbox, collect all checked values and send them (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a large (~800 rows) table generated by a system that needs to have checkboxes added to them so someone can check the rows they want more info about.  I can mass add the checkbox column, but I'm not going to individually add values to those checkboxes... so my question:

If I have a large table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>ABCDEFG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>HIJKLMN</td>
    </tr>
    ... etc...
</table>
```

Is there a way that I can attach a value to the checkbox *using the text in the next `<td>`*?  So if someone clicks the first checkbox, its value is set to 'ABCDEFG'?

There will most likely be a few checkboxes clicked.  Is it better to assign the value on click, or wait until submit is hit to cycle through the checkboxes assigning values?

I'm worried the table is so large it'll cause some issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        this.value = $(this).closest('td').next('td').text();
    }else{
        this.value = "";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle. I think it will do what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/yFJsk/

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var selected = "";
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            selected += $(this).parent().siblings("td").text() + ",";
        }
    });
    alert(selected);
});
```

Basically, we are getting all of the values when the submit button is pressed and building a comma delimited string of them. You can change what is inside the if statement of the each function to do what ever you want with the selected values.